# Show that a given set is both closed and open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that the set

$$B(X,M)=\left \{ f:X\rightarrow M: f \text{ is bounded}\right \}\subset M^X$$

is both closed and open.

EDIT:

I know that

$f(X)\subset B_r(a)=\left\{ m \in M : d(m,a)<r \right\}$ for some $r∈R^+$ and $a∈M$.

I'm trying to visualise this first but am having difficulty

Any help is appreciated

Comment: clopen in what space? $M^{X}$?

Comment: @GudsonChou That's right.

Comment: Now your question gets more like it.

Comment: What topology do you use on $M^X$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489047/show-that-a-set-is-closed-and-open

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the topology of uniform convergence on $M^X$, which is induced by the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}(\min(d(f(x),g(x)),1))$. Then $B(X,M)$ is open and closed.

1. To see that it's open, take any bounded $f:X\to M$. Can you find a basic neighborhood, i.e. a neighborhood of the form $B_\epsilon(f) = \{g\in M^X\mid d(f,g)<\epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon\in(0,2)$, such that $g\in B_\epsilon(f)$ implies that $g$ is bounded?
2. Now if $h$ is unbounded, can you use part 1. to show that some small neighborhood around $h$ can only contain unbounded maps $X\to M$, and deduce that the set of unbounded maps is open?