# Show that a set is closed and open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

We say that $f: X \to M$ is bounded if $f(X) \subset B_r(a) = \{m \in M \mid d(m,a) \lt r\}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $a \in M$. (NOTE: $(M,d)$ is a metric space with a distance $d$).

We also have a distance on $M^X$:

$$\hat{d}(f,g) = 
\begin{cases}
1, &\text{if } \exists x \in X : d(f(x),g(x)) \ge 0 \\
\sup\{d(f(x),g(x)) \mid x \in X\}, &\text{if }  \forall x \in X: d(f(x),g(x)) \lt 0 \}
\end{cases} $$

We must show that $\mathcal{B}(X,M) = \{ f: X \to M \mid f$ bounded $\} \subset M^X$ is closed and open. If someone could show me how we can show this and explain how a set can be both open and closed that would help a lot.

Thanks,
Helen

Comment: What is the topology of $M^X$?

Comment: I'm not sure, we have literally only been introduced to the definition of topologies and haven't done anything with them.

Comment: @HelenByrne Then how do you define open and closed in $M^X$?

Comment: Well, we defined that $ A \subset B$ is open if $\forall a \in A $ $\exists r_a \gt 0$ such that $B_{r_{a}}(a) \subset A$

Comment: Your definition of open is valid only for metric spaces. So, you have a more general definition of open, or you have a metric (that is, a distance) defined over $M^X$.

Comment: Apologies, yes, there is a distance on $M^X$, I have added it. Sorry about that.

Comment: What have you tried? Take a sequence $f_n$ in $\mathcal B(X,M)$ of bounded sequences that converges to $f$ with respect to the distance you defined and try to argue why $f$ will be bounded as well. This is for the "closed" part. For the open part it is enough to show, that for a given bounded $f$ there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that every $g$ with $d(f,g)<\varepsilon$ is also bounded. If you can't use the hints, just ask for more.

Comment: @HelenByrne sorry but the part "... if $\forall x\in X : d(f(x),g(x))<0$" looks wrong, unless I am missing something. Metrics are always greater or equal than zero.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488996/show-that-a-given-set-is-both-closed-and-open

Answer (score 1):

Note that your metric can also be written as 
$$\textstyle \hat d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in X}(\min(d(f(x),g(x)),1))$$
Then $B(X,M)$ is open and closed.

1. To see that it's open, take any bounded $f:X\to M$. Can you find a basic neighborhood, i.e. a neighborhood of the form $B_\epsilon(f) = \{g\in M^X\mid \hat d(f,g)<\epsilon\}$, for some $\epsilon\in(0,2)$, such that $g\in B_\epsilon(f)$ implies that $g$ is bounded?
2. Now if $h$ is unbounded, can you use part 1. to show that some small neighborhood around $h$ can only contain unbounded maps $X\to M$, and deduce that the set of unbounded maps is open?